# When inheriting ModelForm, initial for a field is lost

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I would like to extend a `ModelForm` class, but the `.initial` for a field is lost for some reason I can't figure out.
I tried the following example, where `form` is a class:

`form.base_fields['template'].initial` has a value.
I've created a dummy class that inherits from the form: `class ABC(form): pass`
In this dummy class `ABC.base_fields['template'].initial` is `None`
Why isn't the `.initial` inherited properly?

Comment: it has something to do with only declared fields being inherited

Comment: Please show us the full code of your inherited class. How do you output the 'initial'?